# Preprocessor and template arguments or conditional compilation of piece of code

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

How I can compile template function with pre-processor condition? Like that (but it is not working):

```
template <bool var>
void f()
{
    #if (var == true)
    // ...
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't. The preprocessor, as this names indicates, processes the source file before the compiler. It has therefore no knowledge of the values of your template arguments.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that with the preprocessor. All you can do is delegate the code to a separate template, something like this:

```
template <bool var>
void only_if_true()
{}

template <>
void only_if_true<true>()
{
  your_special_code_here();
}


template <bool var>
void f()
{
  some_code_always_used();
  only_if_true<var>();
  some_code_always_used();
}
```

Of course, if you need information shared between `f()` and `only_if_true()` (which is likely), you have to pass it as parameters. Or make `only_if_true` a class and store the shared data in it.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to generate different code paths with template parameter, you can just simply use `if` or other C++ statement:

```
template <bool var>
void f()
{
    if (var == true) ｛
        // ...
    ｝
｝
```

Compiler can optimize it and generate code that doesn't contain such branches.

A little drawback is that some compiler (e.g. Msvc) will generate warnings for conditions which is always constant.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works if both branches are syntactically and semantically valid.

Comment: But this way is useful when the code path depending on local variables  in `f()`. Using template specialization will be troublesome in this case.

Comment: @MiloYip, your answer is right, but when I launch program in debug mode all optimizations (except inline functions) not work.

Comment: Interested readers might like to read the answers to this question asking about these two different approaches ('deterministic `if`' vs SFINAE): http://stackoverflow.com/q/16178756/2757035

Answer (score 2):

With C++17's introduction of [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) you can discard branches inside a template, much like conditional compilation allows.

```
template <bool var>
void f()
{
    if constexpr (var == true) {
    // ...
    }
}
```

The code inside the branch has to be syntactically correct, but doesn't have to be well-formed when `var` is false, because it will be discarded entirely.