# Why compiler fails to understand the value of if branch at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm writing a function for counting elements of multi dimensional vector

```
template<class T>
int real_size(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    int size=0;
    for(const auto& v : vec)
    {
        if(std::is_integral<T>::value ||
                std::is_floating_point<T>::value){
            size+=1;
        }
        else{
            size +=real_size(v);
        }
    }
    return size;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(10);
    a[0]=std::vector<int>(10);
    std::cout<<real_size(a);
}
```

Which give me these errors :

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'real_size(const int&)'
             size +=real_size(v);
                           ^
```

That code seem's fine and error is irrelevant...the else statement should never become `size +=real_size(int);` because I'm checking the type of template parameter with `std::is_integer` .

But it seems that compiler fails to understand it at compile time !! Is it a compiler bug or I'm making a mistake ?

<sub>*I'm using gcc 4.8.1. g++ -std=c++11 *</sub>

Comment: Code in an `else` clause is not conditionally compiled.

Comment: Have you overloaded `real_size()` because `v` is a `T` not a `std::vector<T>` in the loop

Comment: @40two I think compiler should understand that  it's not  necessary .

Comment: FYI: `std::is_arithmetic`

Comment: @xyz no it won't. You are passing a `std::vector<T>` as an input argument how is going to pass in the recursion call a T?

Comment: @40two the type of T is define at compile time and It should understand that else  statement never calls a template with int . which it seems does not .

Comment: Have you seen, @chris comment above?

Comment: There were proposals (for C++11 IIRC) for a feature called static_if that could do what you expected from if, but it was rejected.

Comment: @FabioFracassi, I still think `static_if` makes code like this much easier to understand than tag dispatching, or SFINAE, or some other TMP method :/ I do see how it could be abused pretty easily, but if used right, it can make code shorter and keep things in one place.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23982816/819272

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see how the compilation error makes some sort of sense if you replace the constants with their actual value. For `int`, that code is equivalent to the following:

```
    if(true || false){
        size+=1;
    }
    else{
        size +=real_size(v);
    }
```

Here the compiler would still complain that the else body is not valid: dead code must still be valid code.

Comment: does standard says so ? because I failed to find that in standard papers.

Comment: Failed to find what? The part that says that the entirety of a program must be well-formed?

Answer (score 4):

The error is because the `else` branch still needs to be compiled. You can change this into two different functions and then using tag dispatching:

```
template<class T>
int real_size(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    int size=0;
    for(const auto& v : vec)
    {
        size += real_size_inner(std::is_arithmetic<T>(), v);
    }
    return size;
}

template<class T>
int real_size_inner(std::true_type, T&)
{
    return 1;
}

template<class T>
int real_size_inner(std::false_type, T& v)
{
    return real_size(v);
}
```

If you do some research into how `std::advance` is implemented in the standard, you will come to understand how this works, as it's implemented in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Conditional code is still compiled, and must be well-formed, even if it can be determined at compile time that it won't be executed.

One solution is to overload `real_size` for other types:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type
real_size(T const &) {
    return 1;
}
```

and reduce your loop to

```
for(const auto& v : vec) {
    size += real_size(v);
}
```

Comment: you mean something like this ? https://ideone.com/ef0Qcy  , It give the wrong result ,result should be 20  not 10

Comment: @xyz: By the logic of the (pseudo-)code you've posted, it should be 10: one `vector<int>` of size 10 (giving 10) and 9 empty ones (each giving zero).