# Does C++ 11 support template class reflection?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know a little knowledge about C++ 11 template. My intention is to have a template function as shown below:

```
template<class T>
void function(T * a) {
  if (T belongs to class M) {
    a->function_m();
  } else {
    a->function_o();
  }
}
```

Does C++ 11 support this template class reflection?

Comment: Warning: you've reached "switch on type" antipattern and it smells really badly. It could be a sign of poor class design somewhere upstream.

Comment: [related Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23970532/819272) (the if/else part, not the is_base_of part)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and better yet, you don't need to perform `if(...){} else{}` statements to do so. You can use tag dispatching or specializations to avoid the conditional statements. The following example uses tag dispatching.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename B, typename D>
void function( D* a )
{
    function( a, typename std::is_base_of<B, D>::type{} );
}

template <typename T>
void function( T* a, std::true_type )
{
    a->function_b();
}

template <typename T>
void function( T* a, std::false_type )
{
    a->function_c();
}

struct B
{
    virtual void function_b() { std::cout << "base class.\n"; }
};

struct D : public B
{
    void function_b() override { std::cout << "derived class.\n"; }
};

struct C
{
    void function_c() { std::cout << "some other class.\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    C c;
    function<B, D>( &d );
    function<B, C>( &c );
}
```

This mechanism does not require both functions to be visible in the same scope.

Comment: @Jarod42 In the name of good practices, I'll change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Several choices:

- SFINAE:

  ```
  template<class T>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<M, T>>
  function(T* a)
  {
      a->function_m();
  }

  template<class T>
  std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<M, T>>
  function(T* a)
  {
      a->function_o();
  }
  ```
- or tag dispatching:

  ```
  namespace details {
      template<class T>
      void function(T* a, std::true_type) {
          a->function_m();
      }

      template<class T>
      void function(T* a, std::false_type) {
          a->function_o();
      }
  }
  template<class T>
  void function(T* a)
  {
      details::function(a, std::is_base_of<M, T>{});
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `std::is_base_of<Base,Derived>`:

```
template<class T>
void function(T * a) {
  if (std::is_base_of<M,T>::value) {
    a->function_m();
  } else {
    a->function_o();
  }
}
```

However, it is likely to cause a problem in this case, since `function_m()` and `function_o()` would both need to be callable.

Comment: There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0128r0.html) to introduce a 'constexpr if' in the current mailing to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

What u want can be done in c++17

```
template <typename T>
void function( T* a )
{
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of<M,T>::value)
        a->function_m();
    else
        a->function_o();
}
```

Full example : http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MsHnYQNlBcRhTu2C
As referred by @Fabio Fracassi